# White gap between Python folium map and jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, folium

How can I remove the undesired gap between the Python folium map and the next cell inside my jupyter notebook. Here the naive code to reproduce my problem :

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(width=600, height=400, location=[12, 12], zoom_start=2)
m
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here the solution need to use Figure :

```
from branca.element import Figure
fig = Figure(width=600, height=400)
m = folium.Map(location=[12, 12], zoom_start=2)
fig.add_child(m)
```

Comment: I believe folium has its own figure implementation, so not sure branca is needed here, but good to know about the option to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple use case such as setting the figure size, it is easier to use `folium.Figure`. If instead you want to create subplots and have more granular control than you should use `branca`.

Example:

```python
import folium
f = folium.Figure(width=600, height=400)
m = folium.Map(location=[12, 12], zoom_start=2).add_to(f)
m
```